# Excel: Check if cell contains number in text string

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet with text strings in each cell (article title). I'd like to know if a cell contains a number. For example:

```
'This is 3' --> TRUE
'Red balloon' --> FALSE
' It's 10 things' --> TRUE
```

**Update**: Every answer on here works. I just chose the shortest and simplest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Similar to XOR LX's Answer but 2 chars shorter

```
=COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1))>0
```

Comment: Brilliant, never knew you could use arrays in Excel in that manner!

Answer (score 3):

Not a very rigorous description, I'm afraid.

Perhaps:

`=OR(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1)))`

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Here is one formula that would do it using average:

```
=LEN(A1)<>AVERAGE((LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},""))))
```

or you could use small:

```
=LEN(A1)<>SMALL(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"")),1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a VBA function:

```
Public Function NumberInThere(r As Range)
    Dim v As String, L As Long, i As Long
    NumberInThere = False
    v = r.Text
    L = Len(v)

    For i = 1 To L
        If IsNumeric(Mid(v, i, 1)) Then
            NumberInThere = True
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```