# Finding a substring that is comprised of both letters and numbers in excel

Tags: excel, string

I'm currently dealing with a mess of a data set that needs analysis. It was uploaded from a legacy database that just concatenated all the fields together, but different fields were empty for different data points, so there is no easy way to split them.

I have determined that I can extract useful information out of it if I can split the string on the first occurrence of a word containing both letters and numbers (eg. abc123). Unfortunately, I'm unable to use a macro enabled workbook for this, so no VBA or regex to make it easy.

Is there anyway to determine if a string or substring has a combination of letters and numbers?

Example data:

2283-332-44543 CAP DDT@ PPL445 HEEN PAX 77820

44372-33-3223 TYYTE CAP BOX 1550 244 BOX PPSSA223 PAX

PRECISE 77 CLEAR BLUE 99WIE BOX 4403 PAX SSKA

Comment: Worksheet formulas don't have wildcards which discriminate between letters and numbers, so there's no striaghtforward way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Check if cell contains number in text string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374123/excel-check-if-cell-contains-number-in-text-string)

Comment: What's up with not being able to use VBA? If it's your job to deal with this type of data then that restriction seems like nonsense.

Comment: @TimWilliams It's on a secure system with patient sensitive data. Unfortunately, the sys admin in charge of it won't let me use anything besides standard workbooks. Trust me, I've tried.

Comment: Tell him it's safer to work on paper. He shouldn't let you work on a computer in the first place!

Comment: That sounds like bad reasoning, but I understand that does exist in the workplace ;-/

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is possible.

Comment: You can usually still run VBA and just save the output in a regular workbook without saving your code. It's not ideal, but in a pinch, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The first block (C1:C3) is the source data. The second (C5:K5) after parsing (a copy) of that with Text to Columns, Space delimited. The third block has this horrible formula in C9 (copied across and down to suit):

```
   =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C5,0,""),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,""),"-","")
```

The fourth block under the rest has this in C13, copied across and down to suit:

```
=AND(LEN(C9)<>0,LEN(C9)<>LEN(C5))
```

To avoid getting in the way of blocks of unknown length, this:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,(C13:K13),0)
```

is in A13 and copied down to suit. The 'output' is in B13 and below, ready for Copy, Paste Special, Values somewhere suitable and then parsing with pipe as the delimiter.

[image: SO44359450 example]

The results from the example should be, in two columns:

```
2283-332-44543 CAP DDT@ PPL445                      EEN PAX 77820
44372-33-3223 TYYTE CAP BOX 1550 244 BOX PPSSA223   AX
PRECISE 77 CLEAR BLUE 99WIE                         OX 4403 PAX SSKA
```

Comment: Very similar to how I ended up solving it, just used a slightly different formula than that nested substitution formula.

Answer (score 0):

I managed an awful solution that seemed to work:

First, split the data using text to columns. Then, for each cell, use:

```
=AND(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2))>0, NOT(ISNUMBER(A2)) )
```

After that, it was easy to concatenate all the ones proceeding the first true together, giving me actual useful data.

Thanks everyone for the help.