Conditional formatting in Excel: format cells without numbers, or format cells containing text only
I recently learned that the listers I paid to write accurate titles often forgot to include a size. I have 10,000+ rows of data and I must identify each one missing a size.
At first I thought it would be easy: just find the cells without numbers in it.  However I cannot figure out how to ask Excel to do that.
Please see Photo. Thank you for any help you can offer.
What I tried is visible in the photo I included.


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sample text data would be better. Images are looked down on here. It won't guarantee that they have put an actual size in but matching and highlighting any that do not contain "Size " might be a reasonable start. You might be better off exporting it to CSV and using something more capable to match on regular expressions to find "Size ". But I don't think Excel can do that. It is an obvious flaw in Excel :( Regex matching has been possible elsewhere for many decades.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374123/excel-check-if-cell-contains-number-in-text-string

Please explain why size wouldn't work (note the leading and trailing spaces)?

find the cells without numbers... Even if you do it, there are examples which contains other numbers.
